# Filter with VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, filter, vue.js

I am very new with VueJS so my question is very simple. I cannot use vue filter. Please help me fix the problem.
My html file is shown as followed. When I try this code the item in v-for can't be shown and also the it has error Failed to resolve filter: uppercase. 
Can any one tell me why?

```
    <div id="pan" class="pan">
     <div v-for="item in list|orderBy 'level'" >{{item.id}}</div>
        <span>{{message | uppercase}}</span>
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var pan = new Vue({
  el: '#pan',

  data: {
    list: [
      { name: '東京', id:"TOKYO",level:"2"},
      { name: '全国',id:"JAPAN",level:"1" },
      { name: '関東',id:"KANTO",level:"0"  },


    ],
    message:"hello"
  }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using vuejs2, with vuejs2 uppercase filter has been [removed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-uppercase-Filter). You will have to use [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) for this, like following:

```
<span>{{message.toUpperCase()}}</span>
```

see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8uv1wqs6/).

Similarly [orderBy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter) filter also has been removed, vuejs2 suggests to use  lodash’s [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#orderBy) (or possibly [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#sortBy)) in a computed property:

**HTML**

```
<p v-for="item in orderedList">{{ item.name }}</p>
```

**vue**

```
computed: {
  orderedList: function () {
    return _.orderBy(this.list, 'level')
  }
}
```

Here is [demo with orderBy](https://jsfiddle.net/8uv1wqs6/1/).

Comment: what about orderBy function ?

Comment: @TanapatRUENGSATRA Yes [orderBy](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter) also has been removed

Comment: so what function can I use for orderBy feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property.

Markup:

```
<div id="pan" class="pan">
     <div v-for="item in orderedList" >{{ item.id }}</div>
     <span class="pan__title">{{ message }}</span>
</div>
```

Definition inside of Vue:

```
data(){
    sortKey : 'level'
},
computed : {
    orderedList(){ return this.list.sort(this.sorter) }
},
methods : {
    sorter(a,b){ return a[this.sortKey] > b[this.sortKey] }
}
```

And then you can change order of the elements in `orderedList` by modifying `sortKey` (using `v-model="sortKey"` to any kind of input, like `<select></select>` or any other way).

[Here is an example based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/panamaprophet/19drnrgt/)

---

And what about uppercase, I prefer to control a view with css, and [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) property can solve this: `.pan__title { text-transform: uppercase; }`. But you can define a computed property for this one too or keep it inline with `{{ message.toUpperCase() }}`.

Comment: Thank you for your commend. It is really useful