# Vue.js: uppercase doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, uppercase

i have this code:

```
data: {
    cols: ['nome', 'data', 'size', 'ext'],
    items: []
},
```

I would need to turn the text into uppercase.
I tried this way, following the examples of the official site:

```
<th v-for="col in cols">
  {{col | uppercase}}
</th>
```

However, the text remains in lowercase.
do you know why??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713941/filter-with-vuejs, if you're using VueJS 2 uppercase has been removed. You will have to use toUpperCase(), like so : `<p>{{col.toUpperCase()}}</p>`.

Answer (score 37):

There's an alternative and simpler way to do this. Instead of using @wostex's approach for filters, you can use Javascript directly inside double bracket notation.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cols: ['nome', 'data', 'size', 'ext']
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th v-for="col in cols">
        {{ col.toUpperCase() }}
      </th>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but am only looking for the first letter being uppercase

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly `word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)`.  Uppercases the first letter then appends the string minus the first character.

Comment: this is better to do it like this instead of  the vue filter way. the reason for that is becuase the syntax of filter | soon enough gonna to be javascript itself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator its called the pipe line synatx. and actually its work kind of diffrent way than its work in vue. and soon enough you will began to be confuse with this. is it vue or pipe js.

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly Another alternative method is to use CSS `text-transform: captitalize`.

Answer (score 15):

There are no built-in filters in Vue.js sinse 2.x, so you need to define a filter manually:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cols: ['nome', 'data', 'size', 'ext']
  },
  filters: {
    uppercase: function(v) {
      return v.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th v-for="col in cols">
        {{col | uppercase}}
      </th>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to add filter:

1. when new Vue

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {},
    methods: {},
    filters: {
        uppercase: function (value) {
            if (!value) return ''
            return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
        }
    }
})
```

2. before new Vue (Global)

```
Vue.filter('uppercase', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you only have to do the next:

```
`<th v-for="col in cols">
    {{col = col.toUpperCase()}}
 </th>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for VueJS / Javascript implementation, but I wanted to share what I did from my end as well. I highly recommend just use CSS on this part to save some processing. Yes, I know the uppercase first word implementation in Vue speed is only less significant, but if you prefer saving brain power, then CSS `text-transform: capitalize` would do just fine since its only UI that you are concerned of, right? Here's some reference https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp