# How do I make the first letter uppercase in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want the first letter of this data to be Uppercase

```html
<li>{{error}}</li>
```

how can i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js: uppercase doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493564/vue-js-uppercase-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1: String interpolation

You could use [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) on the first character of `error`, and append the remaining characters with [`slice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice). Do this directly in the string interpolation (i.e., the curly brackets in the template).

```html
<li>{{ error[0].toUpperCase() + error.slice(1) }}</li>
```

### Option 2: Computed prop

Similar to the above, you could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to create the string, and render that in the string interpolation:

```html
<li>{{ computedError }}</li>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    computedError() {
      return this.error[0].toUpperCase() + this.error.slice(1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### Option 3: CSS `text-transform: capitalize`

Instead of JavaScript, you could do this with CSS, using [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform):

```html
<li class="error">{{ error }}</li>

<style scoped>
.error {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
</style>
```